# c# Game Inventory Item Remove

Tags: c#

I have a small problem about my inventory system. When there is one item, i can remove only one however when i collect 15 items, inventory deletes 15 items at once. I want to sell only one item each time i remove an item. Can you help me to figure out that problem?

Inventory CS

```
namespace SimpleInventory
{
    public class Inventory : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [Header("InventoryUI")]
        [SerializeField] private UI.InventoryUI inventoryUI = null;

        private Dictionary<Item, int> inventory = new Dictionary<Item, int>();

        public Dictionary<Item, int> GetInventory => inventory;
        public int NumUniqueItems => inventory.Count;
        public delegate void OnInventoryChange();
        public OnInventoryChange onInventoryChange;

        public delegate void OnAddNewItem(Item item, int count);
        public OnAddNewItem onAddNewItem;

        public Text additemtext;

        private void Start()
        {
            if (inventoryUI)
                inventoryUI.InitializeUI(this);

            additemtext.enabled = false;
        }

        public void AddToInventory(Item item, int count = 1)
        {
            if (!inventory.ContainsKey(item))
                inventory.Add(item, count);
            else
                inventory[item] += count;

            Debug.Log($"Added { count} of { item.name} to the inventory");
            StartCoroutine(itemTextnum());
            additemtext.text = "+ " + count + " "+ item.name + " collected";

            onInventoryChange?.Invoke();
        }

        public void RemoveFromInventory(Item item, int count) // item satma,
        {
            if (!inventory.ContainsKey(item))
                throw new System.Exception("the dictionary does not contain that item");

            if (inventory[item] >= count)
                inventory[item] -= count;
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("count to zero");
                inventory[item] = 0;
            }

            onInventoryChange?.Invoke();
            
        }
        
        IEnumerator itemTextnum()
        {
            additemtext.enabled = true;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
            additemtext.enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

ItemSlotUI Cs

```
namespace SimpleInventory.UI
{
    public class ItemSlotUI : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [SerializeField] private Button itemButton = null;
        [SerializeField] private Image itemImage = null;
        [SerializeField] private Text nameText = null;
        [SerializeField] private Text countText = null;

        private void OnEnable()
        {
            countText.text = "0";
        }

        public void UpdateSlotUI(InventoryUI ui, Item item, int count) // itemi satma kodu
        {
            if (count == 0)
                itemButton.onClick.RemoveAllListeners();

            int lastCount = int.Parse(countText.text);

            if (countText.text == "0" || (lastCount == 0 && count  > 0))
                itemButton.onClick.AddListener(delegate
                    {
                        ui.itemClicked(item);
                        item.DoItemStuff();
                    }
                    );

            itemImage.sprite = item.Icon;
            nameText.text = item.name;
            countText.text = count.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

ItemPickup

```
namespace SimpleInventory
{
    public class Pickup : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [SerializeField] private Item ItemsThatGetsPickedup = null;
        [SerializeField] private int numberPickedup = 1;

        private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
        {
            if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Player")
            {
                AddtoInventoryandDestroyThis();
            }
        }

        private void AddtoInventoryandDestroyThis()
        {
            FindObjectOfType<Inventory>().AddToInventory(ItemsThatGetsPickedup, numberPickedup);
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What type is `inventory` and what type is `Item` if it is the key of `inventory`?

Comment: Hello. I shared all script. Can you check it again please?

Comment: Surely you can breakpoint the `inventory[item] -= count;` line and find out either if it's being called with a count of 15 (all items are gone at once) or if it's being called 15 times in a row (remove one at a time) etc

Comment: Hello. I tried a bit the code and i realize everytime i open the inventory, it removes 1 more item. For example if i activate inventory panel 4 times, it deletes 4 amount of items every click.